# LinkedIn image thumbnail missing from shared post (shows in Post Inspector)

Tags: share, linkedin-api

My meta tags seem to be fine and the post inspector shows the image perfectly but when I try to share the post on linked, the image is always missing.

https://goalenvisionpublic-test.azurewebsites.net/sv/event/7-varje-artikel-bor-for-sokmotoroptimeringens/?ppl=sade

Here's how my html looks:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#"><style id="stndz-style"></style>
<title>Varje artikel bör för sökmotoroptimeringens skull innehålla minst 1 av  - Utbildning - GoalEnvision.com</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Vision, Mission, Affärsidé och Smarta Mål i Ledningsgruppen">
<meta name="description" content="VD och Ledningsgrupp. Formulera, kommunicera och genomför er strategi. Genom smarta mål arbetar ni med er affärsidé för att nå er vision.">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta property="og:title" content="Varje artikel bör för sökmotoroptimeringens skull innehålla minst 1 av ">
<meta property="og:image" name="image" content="https://goalenvisiontest.blob.core.windows.net/images/7_large_image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="627">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:description" content="sdkfjns lkjfnd slkjfnsl dkfjnsdlfkds">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta prefix="og:url" content="https://goalenvisionpublic-test.azurewebsites.net/sv/event/7-varje-artikel-bor-for-sokmotoroptimeringens/?ppl=sade">
```

[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/)

Comment: the linkedin post inspector isnt going to anything and the above link you provided displays an image for me ?

Comment: That's what mean. You paste the URL i gave into the textbox and it shows the image preview. But if you share the link on LinkedIn.com, the thumbnail goes missing

Comment: could you try a http source for your image instead of https?

Comment: I did actually. Apparently there is a bug in LinkedIn crawling process. Their team is looking into this.

Comment: ah okay, well lets wait i guess. would love to hear if you get any information back.

Comment: @LarsHendriks They have acknowledged the issue but won't fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but LinkedIn have confirmed the bug in their crawler. Here's what I heard from them:

> Thanks for reporting your issue. We've confirmed the problem you reported. After careful assessment, we've decided that we won't be moving forward with a fix at this time. LinkedIn continuously evaluates how features and products are used and we make adjustments accordingly to focus our resources on providing the most value to our members.
>
> We greatly appreciate your feedback and have documented the issue to track additional reports of the problem and for consideration to be addressed in a future release. If there's anything else I can help you with, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: classic linkedin.. well atleast others will now know.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, any suggestions ? @user869375

Comment: Not really. It was not in our control so we left it like it was.

Answer (score 0):

so when helping someone else i discoverd this, hopefully this/was the case with you.

> The first time that LinkedIn's crawlers visit a webpage when asked to
>   share content via a URL, the data it finds (Open Graph values or our
>   own analysis) will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days.
>
> This means that if you subsequently change the article's description,
>   upload a new image, fix a typo in the title, etc., you will not see
>   the change represented during any subsequent attempts to share the
>   page until the cache has expired and the crawler is forced to revisit
>   the page to retrieve fresh content.
>
> If you make API calls that directly provide the content to be shared
>   rather than by a URL that requires analysis, LinkedIn will always use
>   the values you provide.

source: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin