# Linkedin post inspector can't display preview for my webpage

Tags: wordpress, post, linkedin-api, inspector

I manage a website based on WordPress and I want to share posts in linkedin.

In the header section of the posts I have the OpenGraph meta properties as this link https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687 says.

Here I post metas in the header section of one page of my site:

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>El Ivie es galardonado con el Premio Economía 3 a la Trayectoria Investigadora - Web IvieWeb Ivie</title>
<meta name='twitter:card' content='summary_large_image'/>
<meta name='twitter:description' content='Cada año, con motivo del aniversario de la revista Economía 3, se conceden los Premios Economía 3, reconocimiento a la trayectoria y labor que realizan las empresas, entidades e instituciones de la Comunidad Valenciana en favor del crecimiento económico y social. En su edición correspondiente al ejercicio de 2015, el Jurado de los Premios Economía 3 ha decidido otorgar [&hellip;]'/>
<meta name='twitter:title' content='El Ivie es galardonado con el Premio Economía 3 a la Trayectoria Investigadora'/>
<meta name='twitter:site' content='@ivie_news'/>
<meta name='twitter:image' content='https://www.ivie.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/PremioECO3.jpg'/>
<meta name='twitter:creator' content='@ivie_news'/>
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="El Ivie es galardonado con el Premio Economía 3 a la Trayectoria Investigadora" />
<meta name="image" property="og:image" content="https://www.ivie.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/PremioECO3.jpg" />
<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="Cada año, con motivo del aniversario de la revista Economía 3, se conceden los Premios Economía 3, reconocimiento a la trayectoria y labor que realizan las empresas, entidades e instituciones de la Comunidad Valenciana en favor del crecimiento económico y social. En su edición correspondiente al ejercicio de 2015, el Jurado de los Premios Economía 3 ha decidido otorgar [&hellip;]" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.ivie.es/es_ES/el-ivie-es-galardonado-con-el-premio-economia-3-a-la-trayectoria-investigadora/" />
    <meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://www.ivie.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-Favicon-270x270.png" />

</head>
```

I am trying to check in the linkedin's post inspector https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ my url, but the response is always

**We cannot display a preview for this URL.**

And in the Ingestion feedback says

**We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL.**

In fact the json response is the following:

```
{"warnings":[],"errors":[{"message":"We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL.","category":"HTTP_FETCH"}],"info":[],"urlRedirectTrail":{"trail":[{"httpStatus":0,"url":"https://www.ivie.es/es_ES/el-ivie-es-galardonado-con-el-premio-economia-3-a-la-trayectoria-investigadora/"}],"created":1540548016532,"state":"BAD_RESPONSE","lastModified":1540548016532,"key":"https://www.ivie.es/es_ES/el-ivie-es-galardonado-con-el-premio-economia-3-a-la-trayectoria-investigadora/"}}
```

In the webserver logs I can't see any entrance to the url, so I think inspector is not inspecting anything.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedIn image thumbnail missing from shared post (shows in Post Inspector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638529/linkedin-image-thumbnail-missing-from-shared-post-shows-in-post-inspector)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of investigation, the problem was the SSL configuration of the Apache Server.

I added `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` lines in the :443 VirtualHost and LinkedIn Post Inspector worked again

I hope this helps someone else

Comment: can you explain more about what you mean here???