# Thumbnail for linked website not showing up on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I perfectly followed the following links, but I'm still not able to make the og thumnail from my website show up.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares

My website: https://maximumrepair.be

Here follow the screenhots that I took:

The LinkedIn example
[image: LinkedIn example]

My code
[image]

[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think you can't use svg as image, try jpeg or png.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedIn image thumbnail missing from shared post (shows in Post Inspector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638529/linkedin-image-thumbnail-missing-from-shared-post-shows-in-post-inspector)