# LinkedIn can't scrape OpenGraph info from URL

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share my blogs on social media, so I'm using Open Graph tags to inform the social networks of my content. It works with every site except LinkedIn (and apparently also Whatsapp).

Here is the OG info:
https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fanotherconcept.nl%2F2018%2F11%2F12%2Fhet-verschil-tussen-bezoekers-contacten-en-klanten%2F

Here is the LinkedIn scrape info:
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fanotherconcept.nl%2F2018%2F11%2F12%2Fhet-verschil-tussen-bezoekers-contacten-en-klanten%2F

These are the LinkedIn rules:
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687

I've tried the following:
- Changed the image from 600x250 to 1512x630 (conform to LinkedIns rules)
- Added a variable in the URL (?1) to force a refresh

Is there anything wrong with my OG meta data or does anyone see another problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkedIn image thumbnail missing from shared post (shows in Post Inspector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638529/linkedin-image-thumbnail-missing-from-shared-post-shows-in-post-inspector)

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of issues with sharing my own site. What I found is that the LinkedIn scraper is extremely particular about declaring the doctype at the start of the document. When I added  to the very start of my page, it started working correctly.

I suggest looking into this:
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fanotherconcept.nl%2F2018%2F11%2F12%2Fhet-verschil-tussen-bezoekers-contacten-en-klanten%2F

The validator from w3 finds errors that browsers will generally ignore or fix automatically.

LinkedIn also seems to want name="" in the meta tags, where name is the type of tag.

So your OG:title tag would be:

```
<meta **name="title"** property="og:title" content="Het verschil tussen bezoekers, contacten en klanten - Another Concept">
```

and your description tag would be:

```
<meta **name="description"** property="og:description" content="Met interessante blogs, leuke social media-berichten en handige e-mails proberen we allemaal zoveel mogelijk traffic te genereren op onze verschillende kanalen. Maar hoe veranderen we de gemiddelde volger/bezoeker in een waardevol contact en fijne klant? In dit artikel leggen wij het verschil uit tussen bezoekers, contacten en klanten. Het proces van jouw klanten De reis …">
```

(note the ** around the name field, this is just to make it stand out - you don't actually want that in your code)

Hope this helps!